# Routing a particular file extension in Node + Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I’ve been trying to write a custom express route that handles all files of a given extension - let’s say `.png` - wherever they could be, so I want these URLs to be taken into account by that route:

1. `/hello.png`
2. `/folder/file.png`
3. `/another/folder/file.png`

I tried using `app.get(‘*.png’ ...)` with no luck. Heck, I even tried putting just a wildcard after all my routes but the PNGs still don’t use that route. Am I missing something? Does the wildcard not include forward slashes?

Comment: Try `app.get(/\.png$/, function(req, res){...});` which uses a RegEx instead of a String.

Comment: Ah, I indeed missed the lack of quotes. However this still doesn't catch the PNGs somehow